# Owin Self host & ASP .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, console-application, owin

I have an ASP .Net MVC app which works just fine under IIS. I need to be able to run the same app from a self hosted console app. How do I do that? Should I use OWIN? What the code should look like?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Update

Now that ASP.NET Core is out there are a few ways to Self Host a web application. One option is to use an [OWIN based web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin) such as [Nowin](https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin).

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseNowin()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Alternatively, Kestrel has also been a popular choice for [hosting ASP.NET Core](https://aspnetcore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fundamentals/hosting.html#what-is-a-host) applications.

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseUrls("http://*:1000") // default URL
    .UseKestrel()
    .Build();
```

### Original Answer

You cannot self host ASP.NET MVC 5 (the current version of MVC). However you can use NancyFx today or have a look at ASP.NET vNext which does support OWIN.

- [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/)
- [ASP.NET vNext (Not production
  ready)](http://www.asp.net/vnext)

Note you can also use WebApi with OWIN today if you need to make single page apps (but then it's not server side MVC).

Comment: @Daniel Little - vNext is released now. So I believe now we can self host apps. Can you guide how can it be done?

Comment: @xameeramir - ASP.NET vNext (ASP.NET 5 + MVC 6) is not released even yet. The RTM date is Q1 2016 (https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap). You must have confused it with something else. However, if you take the Beta, you'll have MVC running under OWIN our of the box because it's the only model for vNext.

Comment: Oops, @PavelGatilov - it cleared my doubts. Thanks!!