# Is WebApi.OwinSelfHost enough to run asp.net mvc app without IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, self-hosting

There are [some](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) examples how to make console application with `Owin.SelfHost`. But i didn't find any info about ASP.NET MVC apps with self-hosting. Is it even possible?
 I want to achieve a node-webkit possibilities but in asp.net technology stack.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478451/owin-self-host-asp-net-mvc) question is rather similar. Did anything change? Anyone had results using ASP.Net 5 MVC 6 RC1?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to the first part of your question is no.

It wasn't possible to self host ASP.NET MVC until the vNext version which is now in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6.

After extensive research on this, I've had to use Nancyfx to satisfy this requirement in a.net 4.0 environment or just develop a spa with self host web API, and embed my static content in .net 4.5 and above.

Note: I effectively use NancyFX the same way as I use Web API (I have a NancyFX and Web API project serving embedded content from a common client SPA project), it just depends on the version of .net. Below is a small example from the Web API project

```
// In the startup class
// Catch all route for all embedded files!
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "FilesApi",
    routeTemplate: "{folder}/{*file}",
    defaults: new {controller = "File", file = RouteParameter.Optional},
    constraints: new {controller = @"^(?:(?!Some|exceptions|like|api).)*$"}
    );

//My embedded resource files:
var resources = Assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetManifestResourceNames()).ToArray();
//To server static content for html I use
protected static HttpResponseMessage GetHtml(string htmlFile)
{
    var fileName = resources.FirstOrDefault(r => r.EndsWith(htmlFile, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    const string mediaType = "text/html";

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        return null;
    var result = getResourceText(fileName);

    var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        Content = new StringContent(result, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, mediaType)
    };
    return responseMessage;
}

//For everything else I use:
protected static HttpResponseMessage getEmbeddedFile(string file)
{
    var mediaType = getMediaType(file); // NancyFX makes this much easier with their  MimeTypes.GetMimeType(file) helper method
    var ms = getResourceStream(file); //.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray()) };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaType);
    return result;
}

protected static MemoryStream getFileStream(string filename)
{
    var result = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(result);
            result.Position = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex);
        throw;
    }
    return result;
}
```