# How to self host an existing MVC4 application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, owin, self-hosting

IIS recycles after every 29 hours but in my case, I am using some cashing in the project. So if IIS restarts I will have to repopulate the cache that is totally undesirable here. If I self-host my application in the application process then this problem will not be there.
So my question here is If there is any way by which I can self-host my MVC4 project?

Comment: Does not look like you can do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478451/owin-self-host-asp-net-mvc