# Adding a website to IIS Express for all users

Tags: c#, iis, windows-services, iis-express

I am using `IIS Express` and the `appcmd.exe` tool to add a website to IIS Express during the installation of my software, like this:

```
appcmd.exe add site /name:MySite /physicalPath:"C:\Program Files\MySite" /bindings:http://*:8087/
```

This works correctly, and the site gets added to IIS Express.

The problem is, that I later need to start IIS Express via command line from a Windows Service that is part of my application. I'm using the following command:

```
iisexpress.exe /site:MySite
```

however, the command being launched from a Windows Service apparently is the problem. Services run under the SYSTEM account, while the site was added at installation time from an installer which runs under the account of the currently logged in user. So when I try to list websites using the command:

```
appcmd.exe list site
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR ( message:Configuration error 
Filename: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config
Line Number: 0
Description: Cannot read configuration file. )
```

Is there any way around this? Can I register a website "globally" (for all users) in IIS Express? Any other ideas to approach this problem?

Comment: I had the same error (`Cannot read configuration file.`) which was resolved when I replaced a double-backslash in path name by single-backslash (e. g. `D:\webroot\\applicationhost.config` -> `D:\webroot\applicationhost.config`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. First, I make a copy of the template config file located at:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\applicationhost.config
```

then, I invoke appcmd passing in my dedicated .config file, rather than using the default shared one, by adding the following (undocumented?) parameter to the appcmd command-line:

```
/AppHostConfig:"C:\path\to\my\applicationhost.config"
```

and when I invoke iisexpress.exe to launch the website, I also add:

```
/config:"C:\path\to\my\applicationhost.config"
```

This seems to work well.

PS: I know the "proper" solution would be to use the full IIS, but unfortunately the project manager is insisting on a self-contained package.

Comment: iis express is a development server, and not intended for production use.  You might want to consider self-hosting instead.

Comment: Hostable Web Core (HWC) is the self-hosting technology.  its a horrible security situation to run a web server as local system as well.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: unfortunately, self-hosting is only an option (so far as I can tell, if I'm wrong please correct me) with DotNetCore, the "new" version of the framework. This WebApp relies on some components (for example: SignalR) that are not yet compatible with DotNetCore. As for HWC: after a quick read of the documentation, it seems aimed at C++ applications... this is a ASP.net MVC WebApp, written in C#. I don't think HWC will help here.

Comment: many things here.  first, signalr is available for dotnetcore. https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR - but you can use the hostable core in any language. https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/hosting-http-resources

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: that is true, if you fully switch to NetCore. But I can't do that, because I have libraries that rely on the "full" .NetFramework 4.6.x. And the version of SignalR you mentioned requires the new NetCore, it won't work in an AspNetCore app that targets the old "full" .Net Framework. As for HWC, the question remains: can it host FULL ASP.NET MVC apps? That was the problem when I did the research for this project, from what I could gather you can self-host WebAPI but I couldn't find any way to self-host MVC

Comment: Yes, HWC can host a full .net C# MVC web app.  Also, you make a lot of assumptions.  You can most certainly use many full .net libraries with a dotnetcore 2.0 app.  It works, I've done it.  But, it depends on the libraries. but i'm not suggesting you move to dotnetcore, just countering your false assumptions about it.  Stay with full .net, there are many options.

Comment: Thanks for the info about HWC... my "assumption" that MVC apps couldn't self-host came from hours of searching on google... search anything along the lines of "self host asp.net MVC" or similar queries and you'll find pages and pages of people either saying it can't be done or saying only AspNetCore can do it. Even several questions here on SO pointed that out, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25478451/300741
Thanks for pointing out it's not true, I will definetly do some experimentation with HWC + MVC